# Rigorous proof for Theorem 7.7 in Loring Tu

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, equivalence-relations

Theorem 7.7 is stated and proved as follows in Loring Tu's *An Introduction to manifolds*:
[image]

However, it seems that the deduction which involves Figure 7.4 in the proof is not so rigorous, so I want to know if there's a deduction involving only pure logic, rather than graphs.

Comment: The proof does not rely on the picture. The picture is there as an aid to help you follow the proof and see how one might come up with it.

Comment: Keep in mind that you are free to use geometric intuition to discover mathematical facts, including discovery of steps of proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product topology on $S\times S $ is [definitionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) that generated by the basis of products $A\times B$ of open subsets $A,B$ of $S$. Thus every open set $J$ in $S\times S$ can be written as a union $J= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_i \times B_i$, where $A_i, B_i$ are open in $S$.

Setting $J:=S\times S \setminus R$, we obtain the result.

Comment: Why $S\times S \setminus R$ is an open set?

Comment: @FFjet $S\times S$ is open in $S\times S$ and $R$ is closed (first line)....actually I have no idea what you are confused about. Didn't you say it was the line which uses Figure 7.4? You are now asking about the previous line?

Comment: Oh, I was so stupid... A lot of thanks!